# How does SELECT from two tables separated by a comma work? (SELECT * FROM T1, T2)

Tags: sql, database

Given 2 tables T1 and T2.

```
T1   T2 
---------
A    1 
B    2
C    3
```

You make a query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T1, T2
```

What is the no: of rows that are fetched from this query?

```
(a) 4
(b) 5
(c) 6
(d) 9
```

### Answer is : 9

### Question:

Why is the answer "9"?

Comment: What is the context? Homework? Online test? Can you link to the source?

Comment: Could you explain your question more Vishwanath?

Comment: @Vishwanath it was explained well...

Comment: I just found in 1 exam paper.. sorry no more source is available .. just question and option . 3 6 or 9

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The comma between the two tables signifies a [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join), which gives the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two tables. Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
CROSS JOIN T2
```

The result is every pairing of a row from the first table with a row from the second table. The number of rows in the result is therefore the product of the number of rows in the original tables. In this case the answer is 3 x 3 = 9.

The rows will be as follows:

```
T1.foo   T2.bar
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        1
B        2
B        3
C        1
C        2
C        3
```

Comment: Was going to answer the question - but after seeing your response there really isn't any need. +1