# Explanation of the SQL query below

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below is the sql query to select the the name of all the instructors, who gets salary at least more than one instructor.(That is leave the least paid one instructor). This query is from Database System Concepts by Silberchatz, Korth. But i can't visualise how the query is used, aside one thing, that is as is necessary to do it in this way.

You can visualise the table i guess.

```
select distinct T.name
from instructor as T,instructor as S
where T.salary > S.salary;
```

Comment: It's a cross join, see attached link for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538225/how-does-select-from-two-tables-separated-by-a-comma-work-select-from-t1-t2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of writing that query is this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.name
FROM
    instructor  AS T
CROSS JOIN
    instructor  AS S
WHERE
    T.salary > S.salary
```

In general `CROSS JOIN`s are a bad idea.  And here they're a really bad idea.  If you have 100 instructors, you evaluate 4950 different combinations to get a unique list of 99 instructors.
- Instructor001 has 99 instructors who are paid less
- Instructor002 has 98 instructors who are paid less
- ...
- Instructor100 has 00 instructors who are paid less
- Totalling 4950 combinations

If you have 1000 instructors you evaluate 499500 combinations to get a unique list of 999 instructors.

A better idea would be...

```
SELECT
    i.Name
FROM
    instructor    i
WHERE
    i.salary > (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM instructor)
```

Or...

```
SELECT
    i.Name
FROM
    instructor    i
WHERE
    i.Name <> (SELECT Name FROM instructor ORDER BY Salary ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Or...

```
SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    instructor    i

EXCEPT

SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    instructor    i
ORDER BY
    Salary ASC
LIMIT 1
```

So, you're right, it's not necessary *(or even a good idea)* to do it that way.

Comment: @JPG - Ummm, my Dad's Irish?  That's the best excuse I can think of.  Ooops, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's refactor this query a little bit.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.name
FROM instructor as T
JOIN instructor as S ON T.salary > S.salary;
```

It does exactly the same thing, but it expressed with different syntax ( and does it more efficiently). This way it's more readable.

Now, the `T` table is *base* table that you query. Next, you join the same table under `S` alias to match other instructors that are less paid (`T.salary > S.salary`), which means that you exclude from `T` results rows for which such `S` instructor doesn't exist.

At the end you use `DISTINCT` keyword in `SELECT` clause, in order not to get duplicated `T` instructors for which there are more than one less paid `S` instructor.

Comment: It's also still a really bad idea.  Even with a `JOIN` you still have a Cartesian product.

Comment: No you don't, if you have an index on `salary` field. Of course there are other (better) ways to achieve the same result, but the most important here is to explain query logic. It's just an exercise.

Comment: Even with an index this is a Cartesian product.  Take a list of 100 instructors, the instructor paid the most will join against 99 other individuals.  then 2nd highest will be joined against 98 individual.  And so on, until the 100th highest will be joined against 0 individuals.  That gives a total of 4950 combinations.  To which you *then* apply the `DISTINCT`.  On 1000 instructors that gives 499500 combinations.  And so on...

Comment: @MatBailie You're right. :-) Not a full cartesian product but still complexity O(n^2)

Comment: My question is just How it works and i am comfortable with other answers.