# How to only select an attribute one time

Tags: sql

This code shows me the results based on two tables

```
SELECT h.Destino, g.Fuente
FROM Hist_LDS h, gTronco g
WHERE h.Fecha='2020-10-28' 
AND g.Tronco = h.Tronco
```

[image]

The Destinos are 19 and then it repeat, i need to only apeers one time, and count the time od appereance to. I need to create a new table when insted of the information in the variable Tronco I put the Destino and Fuente

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a [CROSS JOIN.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538225/how-does-select-from-two-tables-separated-by-a-comma-work-select-from-t1-t2)

And what you probably want is a simple [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). Not very clear from your question, also check LEFT/RIGHT JOIN.

```
SELECT h.Destino, g.Fuente
FROM Hist_LDS h
INNER JOIN gTronco g ON g.Tronco = h.Tronco
WHERE h.Fecha='2020-10-28'
```

Comment: Esta me da el mismo resultado

Comment: SELECT h.Destino, g.Fuente
FROM Hist_LDS h
LEFT JOIN gTronco g ON g.Tronco = h.Tronco
WHERE h.Fecha='2020-10-28'