# Selecting from multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What does this syntax in SQL Server mean?

```
select top 10 * 
from
    table1 as t1,  
    table2 as t2
```

Is this a union or join? Does it combine two tables together? Not sure exactly what this syntax means? does anyone have online resources for this?

Comment: it is an old-style cross join which we should [not be using](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does SELECT from two tables separated by a comma work? (SELECT \* FROM T1, T2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538225/how-does-select-from-two-tables-separated-by-a-comma-work-select-from-t1-t2)

Answer (score 1):

`,` is archaic syntax for `cross join`.  This is more colloquially written as:

```
select top 10 *
from table1 as t1 cross join
     table2 as t2;
```

That said, using `top` without `order by` is suspicious.